# How to make a GET request in base R?

Tags: r

I see several methods of making a GET in R.

#### Using `httr`

```r
myurl <- "https://stackoverflow.com"

library(httr)
httr::GET(myurl)
```

#### Using `rvest`/`xml2`

```r
library(rvest)
xml2::read_html(myurl)
```

#### Using curl

I have tested using `curl` and can confirm the following works from a standard macbook and from a windows 10 device:

```
command <- paste("curl", myurl)
system(command)
```

#### Question

The third method above (using curl) seems to work fairly universally.

Is there any better way of making a GET request (or similarly a HEAD, POST etc) than the method above using curl?

'better' in this case means works universally across operating systems with minimal coding / external programs/libraries being installed), or is using curl (through a call to `system`) the best way?

Answer (score 2):

From base R there is [`url`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html) with `method = "libcurl"`

```
con <- url("https://www.stackoverflow.com", method = "libcurl")
tmp <- readLines(con)
```

Also, this is not strictly base R, but from `utils` there is [`url.show`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/url.show.html)

```
utils::url.show("https://stackoverflow.com", method = "curl")
```